# Three tables join given me the all combination of records

Tags: sql, inner-join

When i written the query like the following.. It's written the combination of all the records.
What's the mistake in the query?

```
SELECT ven.vendor_code, add.address1 
    FROM vendor ven INNER JOIN employee emp 
    ON ven.emp_fk = emp.id 
    INNER JOIN address add 
    ON add.emp_name = emp.emp_name;
```

Comment: You must be missing some code. You've `rem.address` but you don't have any `rem` alias.

Comment: I'm damn sure .. I didn't miss anything like that..

Comment: what is `rem`? no table has the alias. this is not an executable query.

Comment: rem instantly i typed by mistake.. I corrected now...

Comment: @Mayilarun can you post `what output you're getting` and `what's is excepted output` and table structure would be more valuable.

Comment: a vender IS an employee? What is the nature of the FK between these 2 tables?

Answer (score 1):

Using inner join, you've to put all the links (relations) between two tables in the `ON` clause.

Assuming the relations are good, you may test the following queries to see if they really make the combination of all records:

```
SELECT count(*)
from vendor ven
inner join employee emp on ven.emp_fk = emp.id 
inner join address add on add.emp_name = emp.emp_name;

SELECT count(*)
       add.address1
from vendor ven, employee emp, address add
```

If both queries return the same result (which I doubt), you really have what you say.

If not, as I assume, maybe you are missing a relation or a restriction to filter the number of results.